# Search data from Wordpress custom table

Tags: php, wordpress

I am developing a License manager plugin but not able to search data from my wordpress custom table. Please help !!

table ITEMs are  `licence_id,   product_id,     licence_code,   licence_status,     activation_date,    creation_date,`

```
<form method="post">
<label><?php _e('Input License here : '); ?></label>
<input type="text" name="codename" />
<button type="submit" name="submit" class="submit button"><?php _e('Verify Now'); ?></button><br> 
</form>


        <?php
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $code_qr = $_POST["codename"];

            global $wpdb;
            $query = "SELECT licence_code FROM {$wpdb->prefix}wc_product_licences WHERE licence_code = '$code_qr'";   
            $lic_codes = $wpdb->get_var($query);

            if ($lic_codes == $code_qr) {
              echo  "<p>Your License : ".$lic_codes. " is Valid</p>";
            }else{
                echo"Sorry!! No License match with your query";
            }
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: What do you expect ? what do you get ?

Comment: If the input item is valid or match with my database item then it should say its valid else not valid

Comment: Try to `var_dump( $wpdb->prefix . 'wc_product_licences' );` to see that you are using right table name?

Comment: Table name is correct. and I solve it Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED!!!

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

        $code_qr = $_POST["codename"];
        global $wpdb;
        $query = "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}wc_product_licences WHERE licence_code = '$code_qr'";    
        $lic_codes = $wpdb->get_results($query);
        foreach ($lic_codes as $mycode){
            $final_code = $mycode->licence_code;
        }

        //Generate Message .
        if ($final_code ) {
                echo "<p>Your License : <code>".$final_code. "</code> is Valid</p>";
            }else{
                echo"Sorry!! No License match with your query";
            }
    }
```